# joomla site directs to not found object

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a joomla site and I can enter the administration section.

But If I try to open the front end page:

http://localhost:8080/joomla6/ and hit enter it redirects to:

http://localhost:8080/joomla6/en/ and I get a message:

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13

So how to reach the front-end page?

Thank you

This is the Index.php in the root folder:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package    Joomla.Site
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2017 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

/**
 * Define the application's minimum supported PHP version as a constant so it can be referenced within the application.
 */
define('JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP', '5.3.10');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP, '<'))
{
    die('Your host needs to use PHP ' . JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP . ' or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

// Saves the start time and memory usage.
$startTime = microtime(1);
$startMem  = memory_get_usage();

/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Set profiler start time and memory usage and mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->setStart($startTime, $startMem)->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Execute the application.
$app->execute();
```

And this is the .htaccess file:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
RewriteEngine off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.gitaarschoolvdgiessen\.nl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gitaarschoolvdgiessen.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

See image.

[image]

and then I get this message:

Deze site is niet bereikbaar
De webpagina op http://localhost:8080/joomla/index.php?lang=en is mogelijk tijdelijk uitgeschakeld of permanent verplaatst naar een nieuw webadres.
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

if I go to: http://localhost:8080/joomla/index.php?lang=en

Comment: did you have language plugin activated? try to check if there is Default Home Page in English Language. If not, you must create it.

Comment: Do you have SEF URLs enabled? Do you have the necessary .htaccess file?

Comment: I have edit he post

Comment: @SavantKingOrange Check if "zip Page Compression" setting under server tab is set to No.

Comment: oke, thank you. nice